# Who are Littlefinger's three queens?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

During [Chapter 41 of A Feast for Crows](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Feast_for_Crows-Chapter_41), Littlefinger discusses Cersei's incompetence as a ruler in King's Landing, and says:

> What little peace and order the five kings left us will not long survive the three queens, I fear.

Given that Littlefinger has never openly acknowledged Daenerys as a player in the Game of Thrones, who are the three queens that Littlefinger is referring to?

Comment: Presumably Cersei, Maergery and Daenerys. I cannot think of any other queen that would be relevant to Westeros. But it is very interesting that he includes Dany, since she is very far from Westeros and nothing really indicates she is coming there. Unless you have some nice inside information, which LF might.

Comment: @TLP - It's surprising that Littlefinger would mention her offhand like that though. Especially since at this point in the story there is no guarantee that Dany will ever make it to back Westeros to go to war with 2 other queens...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first two queens are quite obvious of course. Queen Margaery and Queen Mother Cersei. The third is a bit problematic, but we have a few candidates:

- **Daenerys Targaryen**. Unlikely as she is reigning in far away Slaver's Bay, and news of her conquest probably hasn't reached Westeros yet.
- **Asha Greyjoy**, who has crowned herself queen of the Iron Isles. She has no real power and a heavily contested title, but it could be her that Littlefinger means.
- **Myrcella Baratheon**. The most likely candidate. As a claimant to the Iron Throne, and backed by the spears of House Martell, she is a viable threat. Though how Littlefinger would know about this is problematic.
- **Sansa Stark**. As far as everyone knows, she is the heir to the kingdom of the North. But as of now she still has no real power, so I think it's unlikely it was her Littlefinger meant.
- **Selyse Florent**. Rather unlikely. While her husband King Stannis remains a threat (a minor one), she wields little to no influence on him.
- **Jeyne Westerling**. Very unlikely. King Robb is dead, however, his cause in tatters and the Westerlings proven complicit in his fall. So I find it unlikely that she was whom Littlefinger was talking about.

Comment: +1 Good point about Asha and Myrcella, though neither were officially crowned, as far as I can recall. Asha went to the "queensmoot", but failed. Princess Arianne meant to crown Myrcella, but failed. Sansa is also not actually the heir to the North. You may recall that Robb against Catelyn's wishes legitimized Jon and named him his heir. Although those papers may be lost.

Comment: I recall something about they knew Daenerys was up to something, but they weren't entirely sure and they debated whether to send someone to spy / close that chapter for good (death). Response to that was - she was not important enough and when she did reach that level of  importance they would deal with her. I don't remember the specific details of where and when.

Comment: @TLP but no one in King's Landing has heard of such a letter, and they all believe that all the male Stark children are dead. After all, as Varys puts it, power resides where people *believe* it is.

Comment: @SystemDown I'm not so sure. Robb did announce it to his lords, so its not a secret. LF is good at the spying game, and has a vested interest in the Riverlands, as well as houses Stark and Tully. As I was thinking earlier, it came to me that it is not impossible that he meant Myrcella, depending on the timing. If he had somehow got wind of the abduction and Princess Arianne's plan, which is something he might have been able to predict ever since Myrcella was sent there. It "feels" most right of all the options to me, though of course the most interesting 3rd Queen is Dany.

Comment: Selyse Florent would likely be the third, since Stannis is a self-declared King and word of Daenerys is still just a sailor's story at the time.

Comment: @WillF - Good point! Though I wonder how much power she really wields.

Comment: IIRC Little Finger's quote is about how the queens are really behind the scenes controlling the kings. After the five kings warred and and uneasy peace settled, the queens will continue to push their husbands to stake their claim and raise their banners once again. Selyse would have the power of all of Stannis's army, in that sense - by pushing him to attack once again. IMO The quote is more a quip on the "nagging wife" resulting in massive bloodshed. Something Littlefinger is relying on to further his agenda.

Comment: @WillF Good point, don't know why I did not think of Selyse as a Queen. Though somehow it doesn't seem likely LF meant her. I would not say Daenerys is a sailor's story. At this time, Sam travels to Oldtown with [Quhuru Mo](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Quhuru_Mo), who has seen the dragons and Daenerys in person, and it is likely that the story of the slave rebellion is news that travels fast. LF is well aware of Daenerys, as he sat on the Small Council when they decided to assassinate her.